# Install LaTex package from Rstudio

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr

I am using Rstudio through Louis Aslett AMI on the cloud ([see website](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/)) but I am missing some Latex packages for knitr and I don't know how to install them.

Is there a way to install Latex packages from Rstudio as it is automatically done with Texmaker for example ?

Comment: In code it would be `\usepackage{pkgname}` and this would mean that you would install Latex packages in the usual manner. There is a `Shell ...` option off the Tools menu to pull up a bash window.

Comment: the `\usepackages{...}` doesn't install anything directly in that case. Thanks for the shell, it helped !